# How best to combine blender cycles for rendering with sketchup for construction

Tags: modeling

I really love the intuitiveness of Sketchup as well as its structured data structure, which enables me to create pretty complex shapes in just a few seconds, while doing the same job in blender might take me several hours. This may be due to my lack of experience using blender for construction of course, but this "workaround" combination of Sketchup and Blender Cycles really works fine for me using the Collada (.dae) format for import/export between the two systems.

Now I am looking for some good advice. Should I stick to this method rather than taking the time and effort to learn how to work more efficiently using only Blender Cycles from scratch?

Has anybody had any practical experience with relation to this question?

Comment: If you can model the same shape in seconds in SketchUp vs hours in Blender, it is surely just due to you very low experience, but that's not bad, it's normal for new users. No valid answer can be given, I fear, as it could be up to you decide, about what you like, and if you're satisfied with your results, and importing each time. Blender is far more then modeling, so learning it could provide you way more possibilities in the future ;)

Comment: I would say if you have a work flow that works, good for you keep using it. But at the same time keep learning blender you may find that doing all the modeling withing in blender works out faster.